# multithreading implementation read, rotate, and save an image using 2 threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I have written this program that should use two threads one that reads in an image into a buffer and the second turns the image 90 degrees and saves it to a file. I need to run this for couple of minutes and collect some data. My problem is that the code runs ok without the while loop counter but I am having issue running multiple times. I assume the problem is with my threaded implementation. When the while loop is include the output image is just a set of vertical lines without the while counter image is reconstructed correctly. thank you

I have written this program that should use two threads one that reads in an image into a buffer and the second turns the image 90 degrees and saves it to a file. I need to run this for couple of minutes and collect some data. My problem is that the problem runs ok without the while loop counter but I am having issue running multiple times. I assume the problem is with my threaded implementation. thank you

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define WIDTH 512
#define HEIGHT 512
#define DEPTH 255

pthread_mutex_t mtx;
static const unsigned MAX = 8;
char *buffer = (char *)malloc((MAX) * sizeof(char));

void *grab(void *buffer)
{
FILE *infile;
size_t i;

pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
char *localbuffer = (char *)buffer;
infile = fopen("lena512.pgm", "r");

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    fscanf(infile, "%*[^\n]\n");
//buffer = (char *)malloc((WIDTH/64) * sizeof(char));
//buffer = (char *)malloc((512) * sizeof(char)); /

for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
{
    fread(&localbuffer[i * WIDTH], sizeof(char),
          WIDTH, infile);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
//fclose(infile);
//return localbuffer;
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *analyze(void *buffer)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
char *localbuffer = (char *)buffer;
FILE *outfile;
size_t i;
char *analyzed =
    (char *)malloc(WIDTH * HEIGHT * sizeof(char));

for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        int offset = HEIGHT * x + y;
        analyzed[offset] = localbuffer[y * HEIGHT - 1 + x];
    }
}
outfile = fopen("analyzed.pgm", "w");
fputs("P5\n", outfile);
fprintf(outfile, "%d %d\n%d\n", WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH);

for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
{
    fwrite(&analyzed[i * WIDTH], sizeof(char),
           WIDTH, outfile);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
//fclose(outfile);
free(analyzed);
//return localbuffer;
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
char *localbuffer;
pthread_t thread1, thread2;
int counter = 10000;

while (counter != 0)
{

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, grab, buffer);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, analyze, buffer);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand on "having issues"? What issues exactly? For example, what is the expected behaviour vs actual behaviour?

Comment: Also, for your info `C` and `C++` are different languages and you should only select the one you are actually using.

Comment: ahh ok sorry. so program runs, compiles but the image is not reconstructed  correctly. I assume I need to probably make sure my buffers store data sequentially but again not sure that causes the issue here.

Comment: Please put such info into the question itself and not as comments. And the more specific you are  the better people can help you. What does it mean by "not reconstructed properly"? All blank? Inverted? Cut off? Random? Suggest you provide sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: As per previous comment. Are you actually compiling C code and have just used wrong tag or are you using a C++ compiler and just writing old style C? This is important since if using C++ one can (and should) avoid using raw threads altogether and use the stdlib threadnig facilities. Raw thread handles are notoriously error prone and hide subtle bugs even in the apparently "simple" code.

Comment: @uneven_mark, you are true

Comment: @systemcpro thats a good point, I initially started out using g++. So when I compile with gcc and using the while counter I get a seg fault

Comment: @AlexCornila This is a classic producer-consumer problem. You need to synchronise the threads so that the consumer does not underrun and the producer does not overrun. That's a broad topic that is difficult to cover adequately in the context of this question. Suggest you do research on producer consumer pattern and implementations. One common solution is to use semaphores.

Comment: @kaylum I see. I have used mutex locks for the buffer shouldn't that fix the problem you mentioned? thanks

Comment: Mutex is not the right synchronisation technique here. A mutex protects the critical section which prevents the two threads from operating on the buffer at the same time. Very crudely that may work if the `grab` thread is guaranteed to execute first but there is nothing in your code that enforces that. But think about what happens even if that works - the `grab` thread would need to complete before the `analyze` thread runs. Which means the operations are serialised in which case there is no point in using threads. Semaphores will allow more fine grained synchronisation.

Comment: @thank you so much I'll give that a  try.